# Check if all tests are successful in `after(:all)`

Tags: ruby, rspec

In `before(:all)` I set up a temporary directory (`@work_dir`) where the tests can place their files. I would like to remove this directory inside `after(:all)`, but only if all the tests have been successful. If one of the tests failed I would like the directory to be left intact so I can look at the generated files.

What code can I use inside `after(:all)` to check whether all the tests have been successful run?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom bash script, that starts running you test suite.
After that it checks return code, if it is non-zero, it keeps files. In other case it removes.

As a second solution, you can clean your directory before running tests.
In such case, when your test suite is failed, you can go and check files.